# Which Network Analyst tool(s) or other geoprocessing tool(s) would be useful for this analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst, multimodal-network, connectivity-analysis

I have been doing GIS for a few years now but never Network Analyst so I thought I would give this a go. I've built a multimodal network.

**Question I want to solve:** Using street center lines (walking) and bus routes, how far are these parcel polygons from the end destination? I want to know which parcels are well connected to the destination and which parcels are not well connected.

This analysis doesn't use walking/bus speeds/wait times, I want to keep it as simple as possible to start.

In my multimodal network, I have:

- Street centerlines
- Bus routes
- Bus stops (transfer points between street and bus route)
- Parcel centroids (start point)
- Separate point feature class for destination
  I was thinking, is this a Closest Facility question? I would run the tool to start at my destination then find the closest facilities (the parcels)?

Another idea I had was Make Location Allocation Analysis Layer but I'm not sure about that.

I have run both of these tools but the output layers were blank. I'm not sure what I am doing incorrectly, I thought at least *something* would show up.